# WCF service worked with windows authentication, switched to use SSL now it wants anonymous

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis-7.5

I have created a WCF service with Windows authentication that worked correctly.
Now I am trying to add SSL. After following the steps, it now seems to be using anonymous authentication, giving this error:
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

Any clues would be appreciated.

We are using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and .Net version 4

The config file that worked correctly had this service model (server side):

```
      <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
<client />
<services>
  <service name="WCFServiceTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFServiceTest.WCFService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This is the changed configuration

```
        <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TransportWsSecurity">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
    <services>
        <service name="WCFServiceTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpsBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="TransportWsSecurity"
                      contract="WCFServiceTest.WCFService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">

                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15" />

                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the code that calls the service. It never gets to the IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler which just returns true:

```
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler);
            WCFService1Client client = new WCFService1Client();

            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Utility1.GetConfig("RemoteLogin");
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Utility1.GetConfig("RemotePassword");

            try
            {
                result = client.SendUpdatesFromLocation(temp);
            }
            catch (FaultException<WCFProcessFault> ex)
            {
                string op = ex.Detail.Operation;
                string err = ex.Detail.Notes;

            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            WCFService1Client client = new WCFService1Client();

            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Utility1.GetConfig("RemoteLogin");
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Utility1.GetConfig("RemotePassword");

            try
            {
                result = client.SendUpdatesFromLocation(temp);
            }
            catch (FaultException<WCFProcessFault> ex)
            {
                string op = ex.Detail.Operation;
                string err = ex.Detail.Notes;

            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportWsSecurity">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Try the above changes. This will use Ntlm rather than Negotiate (Kerberos) for auth. It is very very likely you haven't setup your server for Kerberos auth.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Switching from Windows to Ntlm did not make a difference.